# Why is the database empty, even after a successful import?

Tags: mongodb

I attempted to import a Json file today on my macbook, but I got an error:

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro:server Droberts$  node import.js
/filepath/A_to_B.json 

development
mongodb://localhost/somefoldername
{ db: { safe: true } }
A
B

/Users/Droberts/Desktop/folderA/folderB/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:236
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                        ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
```

However, after running `mongod` in a new tab, I was able to rerun the command successfully:

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro:server Droberts$  node import.js 
/filepath/A_to_B.json

development
mongodb://localhost/somefoldername
{ db: { safe: true } }
A
B
adding data to mongodb
finished import
```

However, the most startling thing is, my database remains empty!:

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro:server Droberts$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-01-15T17:50:09.158-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are     running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2016-01-15T17:50:09.158-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-01-15T17:50:09.158-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-01-15T17:50:09.158-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
> show dbs
somefoldername 0.000GB
local          0.000GB
```

What on earth is going on?!!! Here is the source for `node.js`:

```
'use strict';

// Set default node environment to development
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config/environment');
var CityPair = require('./api/citypair/citypair.model');

console.log(config.mongo.uri)
console.log(config.mongo.options)

// Connect to database
mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);

var fs = require('fs');
var file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2], 'utf8'));
console.log(file.startCity.name)
console.log(file.endCity.name)

//CityPair.find({}).remove(
CityPair.find({
  $or: [{startCity : file.startCity, endCity : file.endCity},
        {startCity : file.endCity, endCity : file.startCity}]
  }).remove(
  function() {
    console.log('adding data to mongodb');
    CityPair.create(file, function(err){
      console.log('finished import');
      process.exit();
    });
  }
);
```